# Call a function wihich is represented as string?

Tags: php, string, function-calls

can I call a method that is represented as string?

Example:

```
$function = '$this->myfunction($myparam)';
```

How could I call myfunction with myparam? Possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: The easiest way to do it is with `eval()`, but dangerous if that string comes from an outside source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `call_user_func();` function of PHP.

eg.,

```
function callMe($message)
{
echo "My Function was called with arg:".$message;
}
```

and you can call it like

```
call_user_func("callMe","MyMessage");
```

and it will return any value, that the function returns.

Also, if you want to call with multiple arguments or array , you can use

`call_user_func_array()`

Hope you can get a detailed implementation of these in [www.php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)